# IabHelper Android bug (NullPointerException) launchPurchaseFlow?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, in-app-billing, android-billing

I am using the last version files of in-app billing from Google. Today I got an error in my phone when I download the app (I tried to repeat the steps but the error doesn't appear anymore).

Let's say that in my MainActivity I have a button where offers the user to buy some in-app product. My activity calls this constructor:

```
public void launchPurchaseFlow(Activity act, String sku, int requestCode, OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener listener) {
    launchPurchaseFlow(act, sku, requestCode, listener, "");
}
```

In this way:

```
mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(MainActivity.this, SKU_UNLOCKED, RC_REQUEST,
                                mPurchaseFinishedListener, "");
```

And today I got this NullPointerException error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at xxx.xxx.xxxxx.util.IabHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(IabHelper:386)
        at xxx.xxx.xxxxx.util.IabHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(IabHelper:338)
        at xxx.xxx.xxxxx.MainActivity$6.onClick(MainActivity:422)
```

The line 422 of the MainActivity is the mHelper.launch... The line 338 of IabHelper is the constructor.

Then inside launchePurchaseFlow:

Line 386:

```
Bundle buyIntentBundle = mService.getBuyIntent(3, mContext.getPackageName(), sku, itemType, extraData);
```

Which is inside of this try-catch block:

```
try {
        logDebug("Constructing buy intent for " + sku + ", item type: " + itemType);
        Bundle buyIntentBundle = mService.getBuyIntent(3, mContext.getPackageName(), sku, itemType, extraData);
        int response = getResponseCodeFromBundle(buyIntentBundle);
        if (response != BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_OK) {
            logError("Unable to buy item, Error response: " + getResponseDesc(response));
            flagEndAsync();
            result = new IabResult(response, "Unable to buy item");
            if (listener != null) listener.onIabPurchaseFinished(result, null);
            return;
        }

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = buyIntentBundle.getParcelable(RESPONSE_BUY_INTENT);
        logDebug("Launching buy intent for " + sku + ". Request code: " + requestCode);
        mRequestCode = requestCode;
        mPurchaseListener = listener;
        mPurchasingItemType = itemType;
        act.startIntentSenderForResult(pendingIntent.getIntentSender(),
                requestCode, new Intent(),
                Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0),
                Integer.valueOf(0));
    }
    catch (SendIntentException e) {
        logError("SendIntentException while launching purchase flow for sku " + sku);
        e.printStackTrace();
        flagEndAsync();

        result = new IabResult(IABHELPER_SEND_INTENT_FAILED, "Failed to send intent.");
        if (listener != null) listener.onIabPurchaseFinished(result, null);
    }
    catch (RemoteException e) {
        logError("RemoteException while launching purchase flow for sku " + sku);
        e.printStackTrace();
        flagEndAsync();

        result = new IabResult(IABHELPER_REMOTE_EXCEPTION, "Remote exception while starting purchase flow");
        if (listener != null) listener.onIabPurchaseFinished(result, null);
    }
```

Any idea of why? Can be the "MainActivity.this" ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I can confirm this, exactly the same crash report in my Play console.

Comment: Today I also receive a NullPointerException from queryPurchases() function. Google IAB code seems to be very buggy...

Comment: My current workaround is catching any exception, does not seem right!

Comment: Could you fix this?...Facing the same situation here.

Comment: Did anyone figure it out? Its been 2 years and I got the same problem, onIabPurchaseFinished is null...

Comment: Still facing the same issue. Have there been any fix for this?